# Remove background and put new one

Tags: html, css, background

So im having a website that because of my theme struggles on mobile. That's why I am adjusting some things. I have two images on the left and right side on my div as shown on the picture. I want to remove those images and just make the whole div blue. This is the picture:

[image: Website image]

This is my css:

```
.fh5co-bg-section {
   width: 95%;
   margin: auto;
   background:url(../images/links.png) right repeat-y, 
   url(../images/right.png) left repeat-y,
   linear-gradient(#76baff,#76baff) center / calc(100% - 138px) 100% no-repeat 
   !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
   .fh5co-bg-section {
      width: 100%;
      background: none;
      background-color: #76baff!important;
    }
}
```

I tried removing the background first and then placing a new one, but I can't seem to do it right. This is what happends:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.fh5co-bg-section {
   width: 95%;
   margin: auto;
   background: linear-gradient(#76baff,#76baff) center / calc(100% - 138px) 100% no-repeat 
   !important;
}
```

does that work? just remove the images?

Answer (score 0):

```
    .fh5co-bg-section {
       width: 95%;
       margin: auto;
       background:url(../images/links.jpg) right repeat-y, 
                  url(../images/right.jpg) left repeat-y,
                  linear-gradient(#76baff,#76baff) center / calc(100% - 138px) 100% no-repeat;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
       .fh5co-bg-section {
          width:100%;
          background: #76baff;
        }
    }
```